Sequelize Filter Model A Where Has a Model B with Property But In Results Include All Model B's Belonging To A
I have two sequelize models, let's call them A and B. A has many B, and B's can belong to more than one A. I want to find all instances of A that have a model B associated to it where B.id == 'some string. However, in the results of A.findAll I want each A that is returned to include all of the associated B's, regardless of whether B.id == 'some string.
A.findAll({
  where: {'$B.id$':'some string'},
  include: [{model:B, through: {attributes: []}},{model:C, required:true}]
})

But this results in an error, as it's not joining B in during the sub-query. See example psuedo-SQL below
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN C ON A.cId = C.id
  WHERE B.id = 'some string'//this is the problem
) as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM B
  INNER JOIN "AtoB" ON "AtoB".bId = B.id
) as Bs ON Bs.aId = A.id

If I try:
A.findAll({
  include: [{model:B, through: {attributes: []}, where:{id:'some string'}},{model:C, required:true}]
})

Then as I'd expect, it results in only retrieving the B's where id == 'some string'.
I'm looking for a solution that finds all instances of A that have an associated B where B.id == 'some string', but I want the result set returned by findAll to include all instances of B associated to A.
The output SQL would be something like:
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM A
  INNER JOIN C ON A.cId = C.id
  INNER JOIN "AtoB" ON "AtoB".aId = A.id
  INNER JOIN B ON B.id = "AtoB".bId
  WHERE B.id = 'some string'//this is the problem
) as A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT *
  FROM B
  INNER JOIN "AtoB" ON "AtoB".bId = B.id
) as Bs ON Bs.aId = A.id


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

After some research I've found this out. You can use a include clause with your B query with the required: true to ensure to bring each A element which has a B that fulfills what you need.
A.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: B,
    where: {
      id: 'some string' // Filter condition for B
    },
    required: true // This ensures that only A instances with associated B's satisfying the condition are returned
  }]
})


I've tried this as well. This will correctly filter the results, but in the resulting array you wont have every instance of B associated with all of the found A's.
